# For loop works fine in Lua 5.1 but crashes in Lua 5.3.1

Tags: lua

The below for loop works fine in Lua 5.1 but crashes in Lua 5.3.1. After considerable search, but without any luck. `Pairs` is a table.

```
num_pairs = #Pairs/2

for index = num_pairs, 1, -1 do
    startIndex = Pairs[2 * index - 1]
    endIndex = Pairs[2 * index]

    for index = startIndex, endIndex do
```

The error message I got is:

> \'for\' limit must be a number' on this line:
>
> ```
> for index = startIndex, endIndex do
> ```

An example of Pairs:
{1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11}
The number of elements of table Pair is even.

I'm running Lua 5.1.4 on Windows while 5.3.1 on Linux.

Comment: Show an example of `Pair` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I don't get any failures running this on Lua 5.3.1 (closing the two loops and renaming `Pair` to `Pairs`). Can you show a complete script it fails on? What OS are you running it on and did you compile the Lua interpreter yourself or downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: Tested on Windows Lua 5.3.3. All works fine.

Comment: It just might be different data in two tests. Some nil's in Pairs, and everything blows up.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see most important part of your code, but if moteus and Paul said that your program works, in `Pairs[2 * index]` is something other than just number. Publish more code, we will try to help you to fix it.

Comment: Hi Joel thanks. It turns out that I'm using a trimmed version of Lua 5.3.1 which doesn't support division, resulting the error. This question can be closed.